# How to use custom preprocessor directives in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net-core

I am trying to use a preprocessor directive in .NET Core, but I can't determine the correct way to get the directive to be set:

```csharp
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Hello World!");
    #if MAC
    Console.WriteLine("MAC");
    #else
    Console.WriteLine("NOT MAC");
    #endif
}
```

I have tried various permutations from the command line to get this to work, but I seem to be missing something. Here is the shell output when I run various build and run commands:

```
cd ~/dev/Temp/DirectiveTests
dotnet msbuild /p:MAC=TRUE
```

Output:

```
Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 15.1.548.43366
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

  DirectiveTests -> /Users/me/dev/Temp/DirectiveTests/bin/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/DirectiveTests.dll
```

---

```
dotnet run /p:MAC=true
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
NOT MAC
```

---

```
dotnet run
```

Output:

```
Hello World!
NOT MAC
```

I am using the tooling version 1.0.1 according to `dotnet --version`.

How can I properly set the directives from the command line using .NET Core?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The thing you need to set is `/p:DefineConstants=MAC` note this will override constants set in the project like `DEBUG` or `TRACE` that may be set so the full version you would likely use would be

for a debug build

```
dotnet msbuild /p:DefineConstants=TRACE;DEBUG;NETCOREAPP1_1;MAC /p:Configuration=Debug
```

and for a release build

```
dotnet msbuild /p:DefineConstants=TRACE;NETCOREAPP1_1;MAC /p:Configuration=Release
```

An easier solution would create a configuration called `Mac` and in your csproj have

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Mac'">
    <DefineConstants>TRACE;NETCOREAPP1_1;MAC</DefineConstants>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

Then from the command line you just need to do

```
dotnet msbuild /p:Configuration=Mac
```

Comment: Hmm.. The `DefineConstants` doesn't seem to help. Also, when I put multiple in the value I get an error stating MSB1006 that the property is invalid.

Comment: Ok, I found that it does not like the quotes around the constants. If I don't use the quotes, then the DefineConstants works.

Answer (score 16):

If you want custom configuration switches that do not impact other settings ("Configurations" like *Debug* and *Release*), you can define any other property and use it in your build.

E.g., for `dotnet build /p:IsMac=true` you could add the following to your *.csproj* file (not that `run` might not pass the property correctly though `IsMac=true dotnet run` will work after a clean):

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <DefineConstants Condition=" '$(IsMac)' == 'true' ">$(DefineConstants);MAC</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

If you want to go further and automatically detect if you are **building on** a Mac, you can use MSBuild property functions to evaluate which operating system you are building on. Note that this currently only works for the .NET Core variant of MSBuild (`dotnet msbuild`). See [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/pull/1951) for details on the support.

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
  <IsMac>$([System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation]::IsOSPlatform($([System.Runtime.InteropServices.OSPlatform]::get_OSX())))</IsMac>
  <DefineConstants Condition=" '$(IsMac)' == 'true' ">$(DefineConstants);MAC</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Answer (score 0):

Building on [Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743808/how-to-use-custom-preprocessor-directives-in-net-core/43744950#43744950), you can make it quite simple like this:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <!-- Define additional preprocessor directives -->
    <DefineConstants Condition="'$(DefineAdditionalConstants)' != ''">$(DefineConstants);$(DefineAdditionalConstants)</DefineConstants>
</PropertyGroup>
```

Then on the command line, you can do:

`dotnet build '-p:DefineAdditionalConstants=CONSTANT'`