# Preprocessor directives per launch settings in .Net Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, preprocessor

I have a .net core 1.1 web app that I am working on with my team.  In some cases, we need to debug the app using IIS Express and in other cases we need to use the WebListener instead.  Since the WebListner commands will cause the app to crash if it is run under IIS Express, I would like to use preprocessor directives to disable this when the app is being run under IIS Express.  The code would look something like this:

```
   #if !RUNNING_UNDER_IIS_EXPRESS
   .UseWebListener(options =>
    {
        options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
        options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
    })
#endif
```

Can anyone tell me how I can set this up or suggest a better way of doing the whole thing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with your question is that a preprocessor directive is used and evaluated at compile time, not run time. So if you want a "easy" switch, you have to define it in your `csproj` as a build configuration. You have to add a build configuration to your `csproj` file:

```xml
<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='WebListener|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
</PropertyGroup>

<PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='IISExpress|AnyCPU'">
    <DefineConstants>DEBUG</DefineConstants>
    <DebugSymbols>true</DebugSymbols>
    <DebugType>full</DebugType>
    <Optimize>false</Optimize>
</PropertyGroup>
```

And you have to add the information, which build configurations are awailable:

```xml
<PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
    <Configurations>Debug;Release;WebListener;IISExpress</Configurations>
</PropertyGroup>
```

so you can use your code as example

```
#if WEBLISTENER
    .UseWebListener(options =>
    {
        options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.Schemes = AuthenticationSchemes.Negotiate | AuthenticationSchemes.NTLM;
        options.ListenerSettings.Authentication.AllowAnonymous = false;
    })
#endif

#if IISEXPRESS
    /* ... */
#endif
```

**BUT: With this solution you have to change both, the launch settings AND the build settings, to switch between your configurations:**

[image: Build + Launch Configurations]

For more information you can look into these ressources:

- [Creating custom build configurations for the .NET Core project format](https://www.pedrolamas.com/2017/04/24/creating-custom-build-configurations-for-the-dotnet-core-project-format/)
- [How to use custom preprocessor directives in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743808/how-to-use-custom-preprocessor-directives-in-net-core)