# Define preprocessor variables in docker compose build

Tags: docker, asp.net-core, .net-core, docker-compose

I want to make some `P/Invoke` calls from my `ASP.Net Core` application and for this I obviously need to determine which platform I'm running on.

The project uses docker and linux containers so there might be only two possible platforms in my example:

- Linux (when running the project in docker)
- Windows (when running the project without docker)

With the help of `Environment.OSVersion.Platform` I'm able to detect the platform at runtime, so I can `DllImport` the necessary dynamic libraries and `switch` through the `Platform` values to determine which imported function to execute.

Although this works just fine I really would like to be able to remove this runtime overhead and be able to just wrap parts of my code with `#if` directives (e.g. `#if Docker` or `#if Windows`) to compile just the code I need for the type of deployment I'm doing.

Is there any way to accomplish this in an `Asp.Net Core` project with docker support?

Comment: You can pass properties to the dotnet build command. See this question for an example. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743808/how-to-use-custom-preprocessor-directives-in-net-core. It would just be a case of providing these in your docker file(s). I’m guessing you would need a dockerfile for each platform?