# Change target framework depending on operating system

Tags: .net-core, .net-5, csproj

I'm working on a project with someone else; they are using Linux, and I am using Windows.

Right now, I have this in my .csproj:

```
<TargetFrameworks>net5.0;net5.0-windows</TargetFrameworks>
```

but I need a way to say "if we are on Windows, use this target framework; else, use this other one." Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a preprocessor. Take a look at this topic. That should help
[How to use custom preprocessor directives in .Net Core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43743808/how-to-use-custom-preprocessor-directives-in-net-core)

Comment: Preprocessors are for C# code. The question is about specifying a different `TargetFramework` in the csproj file.

Comment: Please take a look at the link I've attached, There is a solution for the project file. The last answer to be specific.

Comment: Thanks! The question threw me off.